# Given a public key, is there a way to find the assets issued by the account?

Tags: horizon, assets, anchor, issuing

I'd like to know if there is a way to query all the assets of which the account is the issuer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can use [`/assets` endpoint](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/endpoints/assets-all.html). Do not forget to provide a large enough `limit` parameter, as Horizon always return max 10 records by default.

For example, here is the list of assets issued by InterstellarExchange: https://horizon.stellar.org/assets?issuer=GCNSGHUCG5VMGLT5RIYYZSO7VQULQKAJ62QA33DBC5PPBSO57LFWVV6P&limit=100